# Python - How to search for email addresses through several Google websites

Tags: python, selenium, email, selenium-webdriver, html-parsing

I am trying to retrieve some email addresses of different companies searching on the web.
I have an Excel file with companies' names and I came up with a little script that

1. searches every single name on Google sid-by-side to " email" and then trying to click the first Google result
2. parsing the webpage to find a match with the regex " * @ * ." that means: find anything in the page that contains "string@domainname.domain" (e.g. info@companyabc.it) and
3. eventually exctract the test and store it in a list.

Unfortunately i'm stuck at point 1 when trying to click on every first Google result.
Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

g = webdriver.Chrome()
df = pd.read_excel(path)
for i in range(len(df['Company name'])):
      g.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + df['Company name'][i] + " email")
      cookies_accept = ActionChains(g)
      cookies_accept.send_keys(Keys.TAB*7).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
      results = g.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div/div/div/div/div') 
      #this xpath does not work properly with each one of the query results page.
```

Any hints on how to continue?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that Google results come in different formats. Some just show the link to the homepage, others also show several sub-pages. Here's an example search:

[image]

> #this xpath does not work properly with each one of the query results page.

If your approach already works for some of the results, then you are on the right track. A fix could be to take a look at the different formats and then include some `try` `except` logic to check every result format, i.e. including separate xpaths for a result of the first and the second "Windows" search result in the screenshot.